# Why is Rocket Raccoon obsessed with artificial body parts?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In *Guardians of the Galaxy* Rocket asks Peter Quill to retrieve a prisoner's leg and he also attempts to get Ravager's cybernetic eye later in the movie. What's with his obsession for artificial body parts?

[image]

Comment: Because Rocket is a  As***le. That's all.

Comment: So his eventual meeting with Bucky Barnes is *hilarious*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They're both jokes. Raccoon asks for the leg just to mess with Peter (and that prisoner) and he asks for the eye later as a call-back to that joke.

> Raccoon: Oh, I was just kidding about the leg. I just need these two things.
>
> Peter: What?
>
> Raccoon: I thought it'd be funny! Was it funny? What'd he look like, hopping around?

And later:

> Raccoon: There's one more thing we need to complete the plan: that guy's eye!
>
> Peter: No, we don't need that guy's eye!
>
> Raccoon: No, seriously, I need it! *[giggles]*

That's just his sense of humor. He saw a guy with a prosthetic eye and couldn't resist. It's a part of his (and the franchise's) irreverent and sarcastic nature.

Comment: In addition to the above answers, he's also poking fun at himself since he is made up of different parts. His origin is better explained in the Marvel comics he came from (which can be found in Annihilation Book 1).

Answer (score 0):

Rocket has many implants and robot parts himself. Most of them are internal, but without them, he'd die. Seeing other who rely on them more than he does makes him feel powerful.

Comment: Is this canon in the MCU?